# Is the audio essential to Limbo from a gameplay perspective?

Tags: limbo

I don't usually have speakers or a headset hooked up into my computer, so I can't hear any of the audio in Limbo.  Is the sound an important part of the game from a gameplay perspective?  Is it essential to be able to hear it in order to win the game, or is its only purpose to provide atmosphere to the game?

Comment: I'd argue that "just there for atmosphere" is rather more essential to Limbo than to many other games.

Comment: Lots of games use subtle auditory changes to indicate something is going on or eminent, most often danger or an enemy encounter. Even just setting the mood can really improve the experience.

Comment: The issue is that hooking up audio to the PC I'm playing on would be a serious pain.  I'd rather not do it if I don't have to.  If I'm getting a slightly worse experience, so be it, but if I have to be able to hear it for some gameplay purpose then I'd go through the pain, I suppose.

Comment: Is there a reason you're ever unplugging your speakers in the first place?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, it's... complicated.  Suffice it to say that I can't always have audio out of my PC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Atmosphere is very important in Limbo. If you play without sound, you are missing out.
Also, sometimes you get auditory clues when danger is imminent. So even though it is not essential for the game, it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the final batch of puzzles basically relies on an audio cue.  Beyond that absolute, there are a good set that have you fumbling through the dark where the audio serves to clue you into what's happening/what's coming.

And as mentioned, the audio is a big part of the experience.  The game's still good without it, but stellar with.